# Scrollable Menu position on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've followed and successfully completed this tutorial in order to create a scrollable menu:

" http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/ "

My problem is that I need the menu to stay in the same position after a new page is loaded rather than reset itself.

An example of the menu can be found here: " http://valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm "

As you can see, the menu resets itself to the far left every time the page is refreshed. I need my menu to stay in the same position.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the instructions there's the following code:

```
  var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
  div.scrollLeft(left);
```

You can store the `left` variable and, on page load, do `div.scrollLeft(left)`.

Comment: Would he be storing the `left` var via cookies?

Comment: I would store it in the `localstorage` as it is a better solution to store this type of stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check some tutorials to understand more about localstorage and then get back to you.